# Iterate over array of objects in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to iterate over the array of objects in angular 2 and limit the string length display for a particular key in the object.

```
this.productService.loadAllProducts(product).subscribe(data => {
      if (this.authService.checkActiveSession(data)) {
        if (data.success) {
         //console.log(this.product_desc.substring(0,2))
             for(let i=0;i<data.products.length ;i++){  //How to properly iterate here!!
             console.log(data.products[0].product_desc)
          }
          this.source.load(data.products);
         } else {
          console.log('Not binded');
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I need to limit the prod_desc length to (say) 10 characters while displaying for which I have used:

Eg:

```
this.product_desc.substring(0,10)
```

Answer (score 235, accepted):

You can use the built-in `forEach` function for arrays.

Like this:

```
//this sets all product descriptions to a max length of 10 characters
data.products.forEach( (element) => {
    element.product_desc = element.product_desc.substring(0,10);
});
```

Your version wasn't wrong though. It should look more like this:

```
for(let i=0; i<data.products.length; i++){
    console.log(data.products[i].product_desc); //use i instead of 0
}
```

Answer (score 115):

In Typescript and ES6 you can also use [for..of](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html#forof-vs-forin-statements):

```
for (var product of products) {
     console.log(product.product_desc)
}
```

which will be transcoded to javascript:

```
for (var _i = 0, products_1 = products; _i < products_1.length; _i++) {
    var product = products_1[_i];
    console.log(product.product_desc);
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I get a TS error saying "Property 'product_desc' does not exist on type 'string'". It seems the `product` variable is of type string, with no way to define it as a product?

Comment: I just copied the assumed object property from Suchivam but of course you can only log to the console properties you have on YOUR object (whatever it is). The logging to the console doesn't provide anything except checking whether what you try to accomplish works.

Comment: prob should let instead of var.

Comment: @Wellspring it doesn't work here as well, even if the "products" of my example is clearly shown as a list of my objects from VSCode.

Comment: If you're getting `type 'string'` errors then make sure you are using "of" and **not** "in" ... For example, use this `for (var x of arr)` and not this `for (var x in arr)`.

Comment: that top one I like because it is similar to python syntax. just be sure not to write "in" instead of "of"!

Comment: I would have never found the "`of` instead of `in`" issue in a million years... Not to mention : It compiles just fine, even in typescript! Javascript never disappoints when it comes to messing things up.