# is possible to loop and insert code inside a html tag using typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am doing something super easy on my first typescript "project" and came to this simple question.

In my old days of javascript there was a way to include javascript on html tags.

I am currently working on a project that looks like this:

```
<Table.Body>
    {nodes.map((row: { [key: string]: any }) => (
      <Table.Row>
        {Object.keys(row).map(
          (cell: string) =>
            isEnabled && (
              <Table.Cell key={row.id + row[cell] + cell}>
```

So, at the moment I have this   and other semantic of a react component.

I am stuck in the simplest thing, a loop.

I checked how to do it [Iterate over array of objects in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213989/iterate-over-array-of-objects-in-typescript) [How to loop through an array containing objects and access their properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626735/how-to-loop-through-an-array-containing-objects-and-access-their-properties) and I know how my object but I am unable to insert it inside those tags.

I basically have row.myObject (that is an array) and want to loop it and have a span tag with some properties of myObject, but not sure if due is typescript I can do it that easy or I have to use a component, any ideas?

I can do something like this {row.myObject[0].name} but not able to insert the foreach code without the compiler complains

I can do this but cannot insider the for command

```
 (cell === "name" ? (
  <Label.Group>{row.myObject[0].name}</Label.Group>
```

Comment: Did you tried anything, did you met with any error ??. In react we can add javascript inside our code with `{}`, nothing wrong.

Comment: If I put anything with {} outside the <Label.Group> it fails

Comment: surely it will fail, see the code you use ``cell === "name" ? (
  <Label.Group>{row.myObject[0].name}</Label.Group>``
because you bind your mark up with `()`, this is causing the error.for more information you can refer this solution
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs?answertab=active#tab-top`

Comment: I checked it, but still no idea how to insert the foreach, is it even possible?

Comment: yes, its possible. Can you create a stackblitz example, let me try to fix it.