# How to loop through array of objects in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, subscribe

I am very new to angular and I am assigned to a task where I want to get data from an API and iterate and display it in a chart. My angular version is 6.

This is the response JSON format,  It is a list of objects-

```
[
    {
        "counts": 0,
        "time": "00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "counts": 0,
        "time": "01:00:00"
    },
    {
        "time": "02:00:00",
        "counts": 1
    },
    {
        "counts": 7,
        "time": "03:00:00"
    }
]
```

To fetch that

```
 data : [];

this.service.getPaymentDistributionData()
    .subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
```

How can I get each count and time and print?

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over array of objects in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213989/iterate-over-array-of-objects-in-typescript)

Comment: If i use of it is saying like Type 'Object' is not an array type or a string type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.service.getPaymentDistributionData()
.subscribe((res) => {
    res.forEach(x => console.log(x.count))
})
```

Try Something Like this For Array of Object where `res = [{}, {}]`

for Object where `res = {}`

```
Object.keys(res).forEach((key) => )
```

Comment: Same problem i am having here like Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: okay it should work perfectly on array of object i think you should check you data again if its only Object or Array Of objects.

Comment: Its array of objects

Comment: Please see i have noted in the question of my return type

Comment: check the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-faqsku) i have used your data

Comment: I got your answer and i slightly modify it as res: any[], then it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use for .. of

```
for (let ct of res) {
     console.log(ct.counts);
     console.log(ct.time); 
}
```

Comment: here I am getting an error like Type 'Object' is not an array type or a string type. What is that.

Comment: Your service probably returns an Object, not an Array.